# Accessing screen properties

Tags: react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm experimenting with React Natives `createBottomTabNavigator`. I'm currently rendering screens as shown in the documentation. I wish to extend this by using icons, but I want to do it differently to as shown in the documentation.

For each screen i'm defining a `navigationProperty` object, which holds an icon and other information.

I'm defining my `tabNavigator` as follows:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    About: { 
        screen: AboutScreen
    },
    LoyaltyCard: { 
        screen: LoyaltyCardScreen 
    },
    Contact: { 
        screen: ContactScreen 
    },
});
```

I wish to use the `defaultNavigationOptions` property to add icons, but rather then define them in the function I wish to use the properties as defined in each screen. For understanding, here's the `AboutScreen` code.

```
class AboutScreen extends React.Component {    

    navigationOptions = {
        tabBarLabel: 'About',
        tabBarIcon: 'md-checkmark-circle'
    };

    render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>About!</Text>
          </View>
        );
    }     
}
```

As we can see in the above code example i'm defining two properties in the `navigationOptions` object. A label and icon. My question is, how can I use these defined properties in the `defaultNavigationOptions` configuration? Is this even possible?

This is where i'm currently at with the configuration:

```
defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            console.log(focused)
            return <Ionicons name={navigation.tabBarIcon} size={24} color="green" />;
        },
      })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up solving this by creating an object of configurations outside of each screen. It looks like this:

```
iconInformation = [
    {
        'route': 'About', 
        'default': 'md-help-circle', 
        'focused': 'md-help-circle-outline'
    },
    {
        'route': 'LoyaltyCard', 
        'default': 'ios-ribbon', 
        'focused': 'md-ribbon'
    },
    {
        'route': 'Contact', 
        'default': 'ios-information-circle', 
        'focused': 'ios-information-circle-outline'
    }
]
```

And I use it as follows:

```
defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            iconName = ''
            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
            iconInformation.some(function(iconData)  {
                if(routeName === iconData.route) {
                    iconName = focused ? iconData.focused : iconData.default;
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={24} color="green" />;
        },
      })
```

I use the `some` function to do a short-circuit type loop. As this function is used a lot I want to minimize the number of loops. Thinking about it, I could probably shorten this quite a lot by using a custom dictionary object and then access the icon information via the `route` key, as these match up with the `routeName` value which gets returned from the `navigation.state`.